# ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am going to use latest **django 4.0** with **djangorestframework**.

After command: **python manage.py runserver**

```
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination' for API setting 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command

```
pip install pytz
```